# else if statement is not run on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue about button click. In the code below when I click on the button, the condition checks if the button's text equals to "day", then changes the "background-color" of the "body" to "red" and also the "text" of the "button" to "night". Here, I want to change the body background color and button text again to the first, if the button with night text is clicked. I am really confused about that.

```js
var buttonText = $('button').text();

$('button').click(function() {
  if (buttonText == 'day') {
    $('body').css({
      'background': 'red'
    })
    $('button').text('night');
  } else if (buttonText == 'night') {
    $('body').css({
      'background': 'yellow'
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<button type="button" name="button">day</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of programming here that is fundamentally a bad idea.  You should avoid using logic should be based on presentation (html value).  You should also avoid make value changes (css) to html elements.

Instead your logic should be based on classes of elements and your presentation should be based on classes as well.

Please read [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

```js
$('.js-update').click(function(e) {
  var $btn = $(e.currentTarget);  // button clicked
  var addClass = $btn.data('addclass');
  var removeClass = $btn.data('removeclass');
  var target = $btn.data('target');
  $(target).addClass(addClass).removeClass(removeClass);
})
```

```css
.day {
  background: red;
}
.night {
  background: yellow;
}

.day .btn-day,
.night .btn-night {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="training.css">
    </head>
    <body class="day">
        <p>velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <button class="js-update btn-day"type="button" name="button" data-target="body" data-addclass="day" data-removeclass="night">day</button>
        <button class="js-update btn-night" type="button" name="button" data-target="body" data-addclass="night" data-removeclass="day">night</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but let me ask you something. Is it necessary to decouple sections or it just delights the face of my code?

Comment: One thing that decoupling can provide is the reduction of causing unknown problems because of new code.  For example, what if someone says they also want the button to have different colors.  WIth your code you need to add more code to add and remove the color to buttons, but with my code you simply add the color to the correct button in css.. no code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `buttonText` variable inside the event handler, or it 
 will always have the value it had at the begining of your script.

Also, setting the text back to "day" was missing in your else block.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var buttonText = $('button').text();

  if (buttonText == 'day') {
    $('body').css({
      'background': 'red'
    })
    $('button').text('night');
  } else if (buttonText == 'night') {
    $('body').css({
      'background': 'yellow'
    });
    $('button').text('day');
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="training.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p>velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <button type="button" name="button">day</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="training.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but let me ask you something. Is it necessary to decouple sections or it  just delights the face of my code?

Comment: Is your question related to @ErikPhilips answer? Because you should definitely listen to his advice.

Answer (score 0):

Move the button text reference inside the method

```
$('button').click(function() {
var buttonText= $('button').text();
    if (buttonText=='day') {
        $('body').css({
            'background':'red'
        })
    $('button').text('night');
} else if (buttonText=='night') {
    $('body').css({
        'background':'yellow'
    }) 
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the button text into your variable only once, thus only get the initial state. For your changing button, you will have to get the button text each time you click the button, ie inside the click handler.

```
$('button').click(function() { 
    var buttonText= $('button').text(); //get button text each time you click the button
    if (buttonText=='day') { 
        $('body').css({ 'background':'red' }) 
        $('button').text('night');
    } else if (buttonText=='night') { 
        $('body').css({ 'background':'yellow' }) 
    } 
})
```